# How to use Android Studio's App Quality Insights to see Firebase Crashlytics on a Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, app-quality-insights

My App Quality Insights window says "Waiting for initial sync..." and nothing more:

[image]

✔️ I have Android Studio Giraffe (2022.3.1) installed.
✔️ I've signed in with my Google dev account on Android Studio.
✔️ Crashlytics is configured on my Flutter project.
✔️ I've already done the 'test crash' with Crashlytics.
✔️ I can see Crashlytics reports on Firebase Console.
✔️ Crashlytics is also integrated with the Google Play Console.

Any clues?

Comment: Same issue on Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Canary 16

Comment: Wondering if it's a bug or feature?